# Make add+remove operation atomic in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, atomic

I'm using `fl_chart` to display the live data, that comes to my graph widget every 0.5 seconds.
It requires a list of points, which in my case should have a limited size of 120 elements.
A new value is displayed on the right of the graph, then moving to the left - here is an example:

[image: graph image]

I'm using the code below to add, move and remove values:

```
List<FlSpot> measureValues = [FlSpot.zero, const FlSpot(60, 0)];

if (bloc.isResponseValid(liveData)) {
      measureValues = measureValues.map((obj) => FlSpot(obj.x - 0.5, obj.y)).toList();
      measureValues.add(
        FlSpot(
          60,
          double.parse(
            liveData.current!.toStringAsFixed(liveData.precision),
          ),
        ),
      );
      if (measureValues.length > 120) {
        measureValues.removeAt(0);
      }
    }
```

However, due to sequential execution, my graph wobbles twice - the first time when I add an element and the second time when I remove it. I want to ensure that both of those operations will execute at the same time. Can I make these operations atomic somehow?

What I've already tried:

1. Execute these operations on some `tmp` list and then pass the result to the original `measureValues` list - *the result was the same*;
2. Using `ListQueue` - *as far as I need to move the whole graph, I need to perform `.map` on this queue, switching it to `Iterable`, so unfortunately I cannot go back to `ListQueue` again*.

I will highly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a suggestion , why aren't you use streams , i think it's more convenient in your use case

Comment: @mazenamr I use stream to pass live data to the widget, but in the widget itself I need to pass `List<FlSpot>` as the final argument to the graph. Nevertheless, you provided a good suggestion and I'll probably switch to streams. Thanks!

Comment: The wobble you mention seems to happen for another reason, which is not visible from the piece of code you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<FlSpot> measureValues = [FlSpot.zero, const FlSpot(60, 0)];

if (bloc.isResponseValid(liveData)) {

     final List<FlSpot> buffer = measureValues.map((obj) => FlSpot(obj.x - 0.5, obj.y)).toList(); // you can use any temporary object.
      buffer.add(
        FlSpot(
          60,
          double.parse(
            liveData.current!.toStringAsFixed(liveData.precision),
          ),
        ),
      );
      if (buffer.length > 120) {
        buffer.removeAt(0);
      }
measureValues=buffer
    }
```

Or you can create your own atomic data structure.
Let me know if this was helpful

Comment: Unfortunately, this code snippet does not solve the problem. As I mentioned, I've tried to perform these operations on some `tmp` (or `buffer` in your case) list, but it has no effect.

Comment: List<FlSpot> buffer = List<FlSpot>.from(measureValues);
you need to copy by value (deep copy).

Comment: Still does not work, even with a deep copy :(